# Ubuntu - How to automatically restart crashed or frozen process?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, service

I'm a Linux (Ubuntu) newbie, and don't know much about command lines and writing scripts. I want to have a process automatically restared, if it freezes or crashes.

For Windows there are several programs available which let you convert any application to a windows service. How can I do that in Ubuntu? Are there any tools available, preferably with a GUI? Or maybe any idiot-proof tutorials?

Answer (score 2):

You should use - install  daemontools from command line (terminal)

apt-get -y install daemontools

detail instruction see here: http://cr.yp.to/daemontools/install.html

and use "supervise" command

for instruction look here: http://cr.yp.to/daemontools/supervise.html

Answer (score 1):

You have to be able to detect if the process in question has stopped somehow, maybe checking the timestamp in some log file for example. Then you can use a nice little app called monit. It's available in the Ubuntu repositories and can do all sorts of things, from restarting the process to sending you an email saying that the process stopped. I hope that helps. Cheers